# How to set the font used for plots in Matlab to the default Latex font?

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, matlab-figure

After some research, I noticed that there's no easy way to use the default Latex font in Matlab tick labels. Does somebody know which Matlab font name is the closest match to the Latex default font?

Alternatively, did somebody recently come up with an easy way to set tick labels to Latex default font?

Comment: Don't understand your question, what is a "latex font", you can set whatever font you like.

Comment: By *Latex font*, do you mean [***Latex interpreter*** for tick labels](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-TickLabelInterpreter)?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the Latex font". There's "Computer Modern", the font used by LaTeX by default. Is this what you are referring to? It has been made into an OTF font that you can install on your computer and use in applications such as MATLAB: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/

Comment: @CrisLuengo Or [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download) for that matter. Maybe the more complete choice? There is also a [Latin Modern Math](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math) font, which I don't know if it exists in unicode for Computer Modern.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thank you! That is the font I was thinking of, but didn't remember the name. A google search only revealed the cm-unicode project, I didn't want to waste too much time searching. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're welcome. I edited the question to make it clearer and actually already composed an answer. I could need some help to reopen the question ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Your edit of the question makes a strong assumption about OP's intent. The answer below makes a very different assumption. I think the question needs to remain closed until OP edits it. Also, your edit makes it into an off-topic question ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...").

Comment: @CrisLuengo Fair enough. Feel free to rollback the edit as well then.

Comment: By "latex font", I mean the latex default font, which can indeed be achieved by using your link to "Latex interpreter for tick labels".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/222676-how-can-i-use-an-interpreter-like-latex-when-setting-axis-markers) must be your solution.

When I use:

```
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
```

I get this as an output:

[image: myresult]

which looks like the Latex font.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly this. Thanks!